# Chrome extension background script console.log() error

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my manifest I have this:

```
"background": {
    "page": "background.html",
    // "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
},
```

Note that the background script is loaded from "background.html" because of some special reason I need to have that html page.  This part of the manifest cannot be changed.

With this setting, the background script is working fine, but when I include a `console.log("Succeed.")` line, the script loads with an error, as follows:

[image]

Mysteriously, the logging actually worked and I could see it in the `background.html`'s console.

But I could not get rid of the error, despite adding:

`var console2 = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console；`

It's a relatively minor bug, as everything seems to work except there is an error message.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console` inside *the background* page instead of directly calling `console.log`?

Comment: Directly calling console.log gives the same error, I was only trying some variants...

Comment: There could be something else in your background script that fails before the console.log is invoked. You can clear the internal state by checking lastError: `console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError)`

Comment: But if I eliminate all calls to `console.log` in background.js, the scripts load and run without any errors.

Comment: There are even some calls to `console.log()` in background.js but they are WITHIN some event handler functions, and they are OK.  But the `console.log()` in the "main" section of the background.js causes error.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError)` or `if (chrome.runtime.lastError) console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError)`? And if you can please add the entire background.js or a link to pastebin/jsfiddle.

Comment: OK, I tried that, and `chrome.runtime.lastError` is undefined (no error).  But STILL the chrome extensions panel (ie web browser `chrome://extensions`) reports an error at the `console.log()` statement, just like in my screen shot above.  The err msg seems to be "anonymous function".

Comment: And this occurs ALSO when I reload another page which has its own content script (not background.js).  So it is not specific to background.js.  (I mean, the contentscript.js also causes an error when it calls console.log)

Comment: Well, there's something going on in your extension that can't be reproduced here using the provided description, do the standard thing: [divide and conquer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: OK, I will do that, just an update:  the error occurs WHENEVER console.log is called, even in event handlers.